# Two different sessions on www.domain and domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, session

I have a problem on my website, that when I am on my www.domain - session is different from my domain session.

My site is built on top of Laravel. How can I solve this? 
Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sessions do not work across domains or sub-domains as I understand.

Comment: You should use a 301 redirect to redirect one to the other, you shouldn't have both operating separately unless they are separate sites.

Comment: @Pitchinnate how can I redirect from www version?

Comment: Just do a Google or Stackoverflow search you will find thousands of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if laravel changes the session name depending on the domain, but you always can look at the config/session.php file. The documentation is awsome!

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session

Obs: Laravel by default works with session files, not the default php session.... I don't know if the .htaccess influence it, probabbly not.